# General Solution of Mechanics Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, differential-equations

I had a homework problem that

> Given velocity, $v^2(t)=\frac{K}{x(t)}$, where $x(t)$ is distance, find $v$ as a function of $t$.

Of course if we assume a positive root, it is easy but what if $v(t)$ assumes the positive root when $t<a$ and negative root when $t\ge a$? Is a more generalized solution possible?

Comment: Hints: i) Recall $v=dx/dt$. ii) Solve the 1st order ODE by separation of variables $x$ and $t$. iii) Pay attention to different solution branches.

Comment: naive side question:  this convention "$v^2(t)$" always confuses me (and seems to mean different things in different communities).  Is it the same as "$v*v*t$", or "$(v(t))^2$", or "$v(v(t))$", or "$v(t)''$" or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use

$$ t= \int \frac{1}{ \frac{{\rm d} x}{{\rm d} t}}\; {\rm d} x =  \int \frac{1}{v}\; {\rm d} x + C$$

So

$$ t= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{K}{x}}} {\rm d} x + C = \ldots$$

Which you solve for $x$ and plug into the original equation.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I'd like to add that if $\sqrt{\frac{K}{x}}$ assumes a positive root for some interval and negative for other, we break the integral into contiguous integrals.

Comment: @Faustus yes, you brake the integral if $v$ is discontinious.